# Why does the y-axis of my stacked bar chart not match the values in my data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I have a data frame (190 x 27) where each sample has a certain proportion of different cell types. Below is a snapshot of this data frame.

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  projid   age_cat Monocytes_EPIC Neutrophils_EPIC Vascular_endothelial_cells
  <chr>    <fct>            <dbl>            <dbl>                      <dbl>
1 02525608 95-99            0.062            0.832                      0.066
2 03052480 85-89            0.075            0.762                      0.051
3 03283241 75-79            0.021            0.876                      0.031
```

I need to create a stacked bar chart, where the x-axis is age category, the bars are colored/filled by cell type, and the y-axis reflect the proportion of each cell type within each age-category.

I tried the code below and generated the following data frame and stacked bar chart:

```r
df_long <- df %>% gather( CellType, Proportion, 3:27 )
df_long
# A tibble: 4,750 × 4
   projid   age_cat CellType       Proportion
   <chr>    <fct>   <chr>               <dbl>
 1 02525608 95-99   Monocytes_EPIC      0.062
 2 03052480 85-89   Monocytes_EPIC      0.075
 3 03283241 75-79   Monocytes_EPIC      0.021
 4 03430444 75-79   Monocytes_EPIC      0.032
 5 03806878 85-89   Monocytes_EPIC      0.127
 6 03889845 85-89   Monocytes_EPIC      0.025
 7 04576591 90-94   Monocytes_EPIC      0.129
 8 05498462 85-89   Monocytes_EPIC      0.021
 9 05522533 75-79   Monocytes_EPIC      0    
10 06073025 80-84   Monocytes_EPIC      0.07 
# … with 4,740 more rows
```

```r
ggplot( pd2_long, aes( x = age_cat, y = Proportion, fill = CellType ) ) +
  geom_col( position = position_stack( ) ) +
  scale_fill_manual( values = mycolors, name = "Cell Type" ) +
  scale_y_continuous( expand = c( 0.01,1 ) ) +
  theme( axis.text.x = element_text( angle = -90 ) ) +
  xlab( "Age Category" ) + 
  ylab( "Proportion" ) +
  labs( title = "Proportion of Cell Types" ) +
  theme( axis.text.x = element_text( angle = 0 ) )
```

[image: Stacked Bar Chart]

As you can see, the Y-axis seems to reflect a count of the number of samples within each category, not the proportion of each cell type. Can someone please explain why this is happening and how I can obtain a similar graph where the Y-axis reflects the proportion of each cell type within each age category?

Comment: FYI for code-formatting, code-blocks use "fences" (three backticks `\`\`\``) that *must be on a line of their own, so `\`\`\`somecode <- ...` is not shown correctly, it should be `\`\`\`<CR>somecode <- ...`). I've edited your question to show all of your code (otherwise many lines were hidden).

Comment: Thank you @r2evans !

Comment: *"As you can see, the Y-axis seems to reflect a count of the number of samples within each category"*. I can't see that at all. Your tibble has 4,750 rows - if the bars were counts, the sum of all the bars should be 4,750, but eyeballing it all your bars sum up to about 190. Also many of the stacked bars in your plot are **very** skinny, much smaller than 1, which would be the smallest value if those were counts. I think ggplot is plotting exactly the data you gave it, you just have a misconception about your data.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at `pd2_long %>% group_by(age_cat, CellType) %>% summarize(p = sum(Proportion)) %>% arrange(desc(p))` to confirm that `ggplot` is plotting exactly the data you give it, then go back to debug your proportion calculations.

Comment: Thank you, @GregorThomas for the code. I now have a better understanding of what I was originally plotting with these data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's summing the Proportion values for celltype within each age. If you then want to represent that summed data as the proportion (summing to 1.00 for each age group) of celltype within each age you can change geom_col ->

```
geom_col(position = "fill")
```